# TensorFlow 'Variable' has no trainable parameters

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras, keras-layer

I'm using a Keras Lambda Layer to make some operations with a tensor of trainable weights (or at least it should); to do that I choosed a tf.Variable as parameter but, despite trainable=True, the summary shows 0 trainable parameters.

```
weights = tf.Variable(initial_value=tf.random.normal((300,)), trainable=True)
custom_layer = keras.layers.Lambda(custom_func)((input_layer, weights))
```

Independently from trainable=True, weights remain non-trainable.
An alternative option would be using a layer like:

```
weights = Dense(300, activation='linear', use_bias=False)
```

In this case I have troubles in the custom_func due to tf.math.multiply which does not accept, at least according to my experiments, the Dense layer params in any way (I tried .get_weights() and .variables).

Every solution to obtain a trainable weight tensor is very welcome, thank you in advance.

Comment: could you share `custom_func` code ?

Comment: This is probably easily solved by making a proper custom layer.

Comment: @newt the custom_func code is just a tf.math.multiply(tensor_A, weights) where tensor_A derives from some well-formed manipulations of the input_layer

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy I'm not able to find a better way to compute a custom layer whose output tensor is the element-wise product of a trainable weights vector and the result of another layer of the model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using variables with lambda functions can lead to bugs as `custom_layer` does not directly track `weights` so the tensor will not appear in trainable weights.

This can be solved by subclassing `Layer` class as follows:

```
class custom_layer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
  def __init__(self):
      super(custom_layer, self).__init__()
      self.weights = tf.Variable(...)        #define weights here

    def call(self, inputs):
      return custom_func(..)
```